# Has anyone deployed the business version of Humyo or similar?

Tags: file-sharing, deployment

We're currently looking at rolling out an enterprise "safe" form of business file sharing and collaboration. Has anyone had experience with the Business flavour of the [Humyo](http://www.humyo.com/pages/en/workspace-access-your-business-life) offering or something similar?

Any pitfalls or issues we should be aware of in this area?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own IT department, you might look at something like Novell's [iFolder](http://www.novell.com/products/openenterpriseserver/ifolder.html), which we use here to great effect.

Comment: +1 for iFolder it's a great solution

Answer (score 0):

At school, we use the educational version of Box.net. It's extremely secure, easy to use, and easy to collaborate with other users. We can mount our Box.net accounts as network drives and work with them like any other volume.

Another option that some of the staff have started using is DropBox, looks very similar but keeps revision and undo history.